# Flink job cant use savepoint in a batch job

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

Let me start in a generic fashion to see if I somehow missed some concepts: I have a streaming flink job from which I created a savepoint. Simplified version of this job looks like this

Pseduo-Code:

```
val flink = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val stream = if (batchMode) {
  flink.readFile(path)
}
else {
  flink.addKafkaSource(topicName)
} 

stream.keyBy(key)
stream.process(new ProcessorWithKeyedState())

CassandraSink.addSink(stream)
```

This works fine as long as I run the job without a savepoint. If I start the job from a savepoint I get an exception which looks like this

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Checkpoints are not supported in a single key state backend
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.sorted.state.NonCheckpointingStorageAccess.resolveCheckpoint(NonCheckpointingStorageAccess.java:43)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.restoreSavepoint(CheckpointCoordinator.java:1623)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.tryRestoreExecutionGraphFromSavepoint(SchedulerBase.java:362)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(SchedulerBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.<init>(SchedulerBase.java:249)
```

I could work around this if I set the option:

```
execution.batch-state-backend.enabled: false
```

but this eventually results in another error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The fraction of memory to allocate should not be 0. Please make sure that all types of managed memory consumers contained in the job are configured with a non-negative weight via `taskmanager.memory.managed.consumer-weights`.
at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:160)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.validateFraction(MemoryManager.java:673)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.computeMemorySize(MemoryManager.java:653)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory(MemoryManager.java:526)
```

Of course I tried to set the config key `taskmanager.memory.managed.consumer-weights` (used `DATAPROC:70,PYTHON:30`) but this doesn't seems to have any effects.

So I wonder if I have a conceptual error and can't reuse savepoints from a streaming job in a batch job or if I simply have a problem in my configuration. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a hint from the flink user-group it turned out that it is NOT possible to reuse a savepoint from the streaming job (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/execution_mode/#state-backends--state). So instead of running the job as in batch-mode (`flink.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH)`) I just run it in the default execution mode (`STREAMING`). This has the minor downside that it will run forever and have to be stopped by someone once all data was processed.